# Modify X-editable templates on a per element basis (not globally)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I added a delete button to the [X-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#global) form using the following script ([live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0o1nud3w/)).

How can this be accomplished for only some elements (i.e. `.editable-with-delete`) and not globally?

[image]

```
$('.editable').editable();

$.fn.editableform.buttons += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>';

$('.editable-with-delete').editable();


$("#list").on("click", "i.glyphicon-trash", function() {
  console.log('delete')
});

<h4>X-editable: display checklist as UL</h4>
<ul id='list'>
  <li class='editable-with-delete'>Editable element with delete</li>
  <li class='editable'>Editable element without delete</li>
  <li class='editable'>Editable element without delete</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the features currently offered by the X-editable library, I'm not seeing a way to do what you want to do just by setting options for your editables.

However, you could do it by listening to the `shown` event and adding the button in the event handler. Here is an example:

```
$('.editable').editable();

$(".editable-with-delete")
  .on("shown", function(ev, editable) {
    const buttons = editable.container.$form.find(".editable-buttons")[0];
    buttons.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>')
  })
  .editable();

$("#list").on("click", ".editable-delete", function() {
  console.log('delete')
});
```

Ideally, in my own applications I'd prefer to have the buttons be added before the popup is shown but I don't see a way to do this with the public API of the library as it exists now. At any rate, with the reflow optimizations performed by browsers these days I doubt that adding the button in the `shown` handler visibly affect user experience.

Here's a modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kuqjtdar/3/

Comment: Thanks Louis!  If I have something else bound to the same element (specifically https://github.com/sindu12jun/table-dragger), is there concern about using `shown`?  Can the `shown` callback be made to pertain only to `editable`?  If not, I suppose I can always wrap some other element around it.

Comment: Also, any recommendations on how to add the callback?  My `$("#list").on("click", ".editable-delete", function() {});` approach is not ideal, and think it probably should be added on `shown`, right?

Comment: Disregard second comment.  I will just add `buttons.children.item(2).addEventListener("click", function(){console.log('delete')})`

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. Regarding the `shown` event, it is possible to run into a clash if you modify the popup made by x-editable to contain other things that generate `shown` events. If that's a worry, you could add `if (ev.target !== this) return;` Regarding handling the click on the delete button, doing it the way it is in the answer is not *inherently* problematic. The event handler is created prior to any buttons being created but because the code uses event delegation, that's not a problem. Ultimately, the best approach really depends on the overall structure of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution but you could add the delete button using a separate click event and reset the html when delete is not required. See the code snippet below.

```
$('#list').editable();

$('#list').on('click', '.editable',  ()=> resetButtons());

$('#list').on('click', '.editable-with-delete', ()=> { 
resetButtons();
$.fn.editableform.buttons += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>';
});

function resetButtons() {
$.fn.editableform.buttons = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-cancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks guy-curtis,  When trying your solution, it doesn't update the form until the second time an element is clicked.  Slightly different but should be the same: http://jsfiddle.net/opdsvkxe/.  Did you try it, and if so, did you get different results?  Thanks